# how to create download file in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the task to download the file in vue, but I don't know how to make it because I'm still a beginner.

I tried this code, but the results actually opened the image on the new page

```html
<a 
    class = "btn btn-success btn-xs"
    href = "https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m39nv7PcCU1r326q7o1_500.png"
    download = "myImage.png"
    target = "_ blank"
    > Download </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the target attribute and the file would be opened on the same page.

```html
<a 
class = "btn btn-success btn-xs"
href = "https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m39nv7PcCU1r326q7o1_500.png"
download = "myImage.png"
> Download </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for current page.

```html
<a 
        class = "btn btn-success btn-xs"
        href = "https://78.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m39nv7PcCU1r326q7o1_500.png"
        download = "myImage.png"
        target = "_self"
        > Download </a>
```